# serialization format with string referencing of fields

Tags: xml, serialization, protocol-buffers

I found [this link on serialization protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats), but only XML handles referencing of fields via Xpath. I am not a big fan of XML since is slow to serialize, large and not nice to read in text format.

What alternatives do I have?

I need to at least search for fields or arrays and ideally add objects on the fly with validation against a known schema.

Comment: Do you want to validate incoming serialized data or the one you are serializing?

Comment: If you're looking for a non-XML solution then tagging your question "XML" is a tactical error - the people who look at the question will all be XML enthusiasts.

Comment: I have the object in memory and would like to validate every time I change anything. Worst case when I serialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from XML the common things you can use:

1. Binary serialization (available in most platforms) which is the most compact and fastest but least interoperable (cannot port between systems) if using platform specific variants.
2. A text format like JSON which is less heavy than XML but still human readable (some say more than xml) and portable.
3. You can also output to flat file (cumbersome but good interoperability between technology stacks).

By the way if you find XML not nice to read you may have a problem with the other "human readable" serialization options out there.

Edit: Incorporating @marc's comments.

Comment: What about the xpath, self describing message side of things that allow me to be fully flexible on the client side.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. If you mean what other serialization formats support xpath other than xml, well - none of them do.

Comment: I like to have some xpath light in another serilization format, since I am not a huge fan of XML.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Xpath was designed to query Xml.

Comment: protocol-buffers and a range of other formats are actually a part of "1" (binary serialisation); the incorrect assertion that it is not portable only applies to platform-specific formats

Comment: Just had a play with reflections in protocol buffers today, and I might make it work at least I can show fields type and sets of field.